# Is it possible to change default sorting in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to change it what happens when I right click on a column and sort it.

I want EVERY column to be sorted by 1 - 21 (b1:b21, c1:c21 etc)

Is this possible or do I have to go to data and do it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Sheets doesn't include a way to customize system menus (context menu, data menu, etc.) , but you could add custom menus and add options to them to call scripts.
See [Quickstart: Macros, Menus, and Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros)  for a tutorial and
[Custom Menus in Google Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) for details about custom menus.